# How can I preserve select default option

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have a select html element for years, I want it's default value to be only "年", but my js code is rewriting it. What should I do?

```
<select id="f_year" name="f_year">
    <option disabled selected value>年</option>
</select>

<script>
var start = 1900;
    var end = new Date().getFullYear();
    var options = "";
    for(var year = start ; year <=end; year++){
        options += "<option>"+ year +　"年" + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("f_year").innerHTML = options;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are recreating the Select options. Instead of keepin  **`var options = "";`** keep it as **`var options = "<option disabled selected value>年</option>";`**

```
<select id="f_year" name="f_year">

</select>

<script>
var start = 1900;
    var end = new Date().getFullYear();
    var options = "<option disabled selected value>年</option>";
    for(var year = start ; year <=end; year++){
        options += "<option>"+ year +　"年" + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("f_year").innerHTML = options;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to keep HTML in the HTML when possible…
… So, I would just append your `options` using `+=` instead of `=`.

See it in a working snippet:

```js
var start = 1900;
var end = new Date().getFullYear();
var options = "";
for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
  options += "<option>" + year + 　"年" + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("f_year").innerHTML += options; // TAKIT: Modified only here!
```

```html
<select id="f_year" name="f_year">
  <option disabled selected value>年</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps.